# Motorola MZ604 can't be recognized as an android device

Tags: android, adb, device, motorola

I have installed "Motorola Device Manager" from Motorola site
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481
It says that it includes "USB Driver".

I open the device manager, I can see under "Portable Devices", there is a "MZ604"; under "Universal Serial Bus controllers", there is a "USB Composite Device". But there is a "MZ604" under "Other devices".

I still can't use "adb devices" to see that Pad.

Does anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Motorola device drivers by double-clicking the executables directly:
https://motorola-global-en-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/89881/action/auth

Incidentally, it gave me an alert to switch to Media device (MTP) mode; this mode was already active.

- Settings

  - Storage

    - (...)

      - USB Computer Connection
      - Media device (MTP) [x]
      - Camera (PTP)

However, when I installed them via Device Manager (per instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)), I had success:

I installed them on these:

- ADB Interface

  - Mot Composite ADB Interface
    ...
- Universal Serial Bus controllers

  - Motorola USB Composite Device
  - USB Composite Device

This allows me to use

- Chrome (32+)

  - Tools

    - Inspect devices

Answer (score 0):

[image: valid USB driver]  (motoandroid.inf and motccgp.inf) for Xoom (mz604) was unpacked from Motorola_Mobile_Drivers_32bit.msi from MotoHelper_setup.exe from MotorolaDeviceManager_2.4.5.exe (Motorola device manger) from Motorola site.

For mz604 pci id is Vid_22b8 Pid_70a9 Rev_9999, androidboot.modelno=MZ604, ro.boot.modelno:[MZ604]

Answer (score -1):

Ghostbuster will clear your devices.  You will need to reinstall removable device drivers after running Ghostbuster.  Download here:

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/ghostbuster.html

Run as administrator to enable clearing ghosted devices.  Right click on a pink area and click "add class".  Number of ghosted devices is in lower right corner.